# How do I send plaintext via Python 3 socket library?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, graphite, plaintext

Looking at Graphite's latest documentation, I see that I can feed data into Graphite via plaintext. But I can't seem to find a way in Python 3 to send plaintext via the server ip address and port 2003. All I can seem to do is send bytes via `sock.sendall(message.encode())` and Graphite does not seem to read that. Is there a way for Python 3 to feed data into Graphite?

Comment: Sending plaintext is easy, you just have to know wich encoding is used. Probably UTF-8, though; wich is the default value for `encode` and `decode`, as far as I am concerned. So if Graphite doesn't read that, it's either that you a) have a bug in your code, so nothing gets sent, b) Graphite has a bug, c) Graphite uses something else than UTF-8, d) client and server haven't got any connection to each other. But I don't know what Graphite is, or how it works, so...

Comment: Do you have to use plaintext? The pickle format is really easy to use with Python (it's in the standard library), and is more efficient too.

Comment: With what I'm working with, I only have port 2003 open. So I can't use pickle even though I would like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code actually worked. For some reason, the graph itself did not update. So `sock.sendall(message.encode())` actually does work for the plaintext protocol.